# jQuery JSON not retrieving the titles

Tags: jquery, json

OK, I am trying to get the title from the file: main.txt, but it's main.txt in the same folder (as you can see, it is JSON).

I am using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="images">
            Hello<br />
        </div>
        <script>
            $.getJSON("main.txt",
                      function(data) {
                        $.each(data.items, function(i,items){
                            $("#images").append(items.id);
                            if (i == 3)
                                return false;
                        });
                      });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However... nothing is returning back, and there are no errors in the Google Chrome console.

Comment: nothing is returning back means you are not getting the response from the server or the success handler is not being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assuming you are not doing a cross-domain request you have the following problems. The JSON is not valid as already mentioned by @Felix.

You can validate it by going to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com).

This worked for me locally:

```
$(function(){

  $.getJSON("SOQ.txt",
  {
    tags: "title",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      console.log(item.id);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the valid JSON:

```
{
    "title": "Home",
    "ids": [
        {
            "currentID": 1,
            "leftMap": 0,
            "rightMap": 0,
            "upMap": 0,
            "downMap": 0
        }
    ],
    "signs": [
        {
            "x": 8,
            "y": 13,
            "map": 1,
            "text": "Welcometothegame.<br/><br/>Outsideworldislocked.Makeyourownworld."
        }
    ],
    "entrances": [
        {
            "x": 12,
            "y": 4,
            "tile_after": 167,
            "item_req": 0
        },
        {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 5,
            "tile_after": 166,
            "item_req": 0
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 7,
            "tile_after": 166,
            "item_req": 5
        }
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "6",
            "x": 10,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "x": 5,
            "y": 3
        }
    ],
    "monsters": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "x": 13,
            "y": 9
        }
    ],
    "map": [
        [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            190,
            115,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            2
        ],
        [
            190,
            190,
            190,
            190,
            190,
            190,
            190,
            190,
            13,
            148,
            148,
            148,
            148,
            148,
            121,
            2
        ],
        [
            1,
            520,
            127,
            127,
            127,
            127,
            127,
            13,
            13,
            148,
            167,
            167,
            167,
            148,
            343,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            520,
            127,
            166,
            166,
            166,
            127,
            13,
            13,
            148,
            167,
            167,
            167,
            148,
            343,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            520,
            127,
            166,
            166,
            166,
            127,
            13,
            13,
            148,
            148,
            148,
            183,
            148,
            343,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            520,
            364,
            174,
            127,
            361,
            127,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            1
        ],
        [
            115,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            115
        ],
        [
            1,
            514,
            13,
            13,
            394,
            343,
            145,
            220,
            145,
            145,
            145,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            514,
            13,
            13,
            343,
            118,
            145,
            166,
            166,
            166,
            145,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            514,
            514,
            13,
            118,
            118,
            145,
            166,
            166,
            522,
            145,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            13,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            115,
            1,
            1,
            145,
            145,
            145,
            145,
            145,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: **Your file is not valid JSON**. Therefore jQuery cannot parse it, and the success callback is not executed.

In [JSON](http://json.org/), keys and strings have to be in double quotes. I.e.

```
{
    'title': 'Home',
    ...
```

has to be

```
{
   "title": "Home",
   ...
```

That's just an example; you have to correct the whole file.

Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON. Your current text gives:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    'title': 'Home',   
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Also the `;` at the end is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://mystikrpg.com/main.txt, the element of items contains 'id', 'x', and 'y' properties. There isn't any 'media' property. That is the cause your code doesn't work.

Comment: YOU ARE WRONG - it event dont get any answer.     http://jsbin.com/ubupov/edit#javascript,html ( we need to test it in the same domain enviroment)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You don't get any answer because you cannot do cross-domain calls in JavaScript. But as it is the same domain for the OP, he can access the content and there is indeed no media property. *Edit:* OP seemed to change the code so that is not the problem.

Comment: @Felix Kling then i misunderstood sry ... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

**Is it in your domain or another's domain? You can't to it for another domain... use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)**

Use `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` **before** you deal with it.

```
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(data).items, function(i,item){
```

Comment: `getJSON` implicitly sets `dataType:"json"` and the json response is parsed automatically

Comment: and the calling page is also in that domain  ?

Comment: Nope. also i changed the code a bit to reflect the IDs and map url

Comment: did you change $.getJSON("main.txt", to .js ?

Comment: Why to .js? It is not .js.. it is a text file.

Comment: look at the above code - they are right. you dont have media there